# Why the "Pause" button is not working in this Stopwatch timer? --Windows Phone App Developement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, dispatchertimer

I don't know why this pause button is not working here. Also my stopwatch class doesn't have Restart method so I thought to write it by combining "reset and start". Any other idea? Or any idea about how to make this pause button work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        enum TimerState
        {
            Unknown,
            Stopped,
            Paused,
            Running
        }

        private TimerState _currentState = TimerState.Unknown;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / 30);
            newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        }


        void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            UpdateUI();
        }

        private void Button_Stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stop();
        }

        private void Button_Pause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Pause();
        }

        private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            Start();

        }
        void UpdateUI()
        {
            textClock.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("0.00");
        }


        void Start()
        {
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            newTimer.Start();
            UpdateUI();
        }

        void Stop()
        {
            _currentState = TimerState.Stopped;
            sw.Stop();
            newTimer.Stop();
            UpdateUI();
        }

        void Pause()
        {
            _currentState = TimerState.Paused;
            sw.Stop();
            newTimer.Stop();
            UpdateUI();
        }

        void Resume()
        {
            if (_currentState == TimerState.Stopped)
            {
                sw.Reset();
            }
            _currentState = TimerState.Running;
            sw.Start();
            newTimer.Start();
            UpdateUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.
P.S.: My .NET version is "Version 4.5.50709" Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.  According to this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart.aspx) we should have a Restart method in Stopwatch class but mine doesn't have one however!

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing? Do your Stop and Resume buttons work?

Comment: When I press pause and then press start, it starts from the beginning not from the time I pause it! However stop button works fine and when I press it and then press start, it starts from the beginning as it should.

Answer (score 3):

If you're targetting Windows Phone, you're probably using Silverlight rather than .NET 4.5, and that would explain why your [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class does not have a `Restart` method.

In Silverlight, [`Stopwatch.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) will start **or resume** measuring elapsed time for an interval.

The logic in your `Start`, `Stop`, `Pause` and `Resume` methods looks ok(*), but you only have event handlers for `Button_Start`, `Button_Stop` and `Button_Pause`. There is no `Button_Resume`.

Do you have a resume button? If not, where do you expect your `Resume` method to be called? Maybe you have hooked up a resume button to the `Button_Start` handler, which will reset your stopwatch?

If you have no Resume button, and you want the Start button to act resume after pausing and restart after stopping, then just change your Start button's click even handler to call `Resume()` instead of `Start()`.

```
private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Resume();
}
```

---

(*) However, you might want to disable Stop/Pause when the stopwatch is not running, as you can press stop, then pause and then when you press start, the timer will resume rather than restart etc.

Comment: so there's no way to make use of Restart method in Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: @MonaJalal, the Restart method is just a shortcut to the role process, like described: `Stops time interval measurement, resets the elapsed time to zero, and starts measuring elapsed time. **public void Restart();**`

Comment: @MonaJalal No, you can't use `Restart()`. You can just call `Reset()` then `Start()` instead. It' hard to see why you want `Restart()` anyway, unless you want to expose an explicit Restart button.

Comment: @Ergwun Actually I have used the combination of "reset" and "start" for acting as "restart" but as you see it's not working for "pause" button and always resets!

Comment: @MonaJalal Is your `Resume` method ever called? (See my edit to the answer above.)

Comment: @Ergwun The fact is that I want it to be in a way that when I press pause and then press start, it resume and when I press stop and then start it start from zero. Actually I want my start button to act as both "start" as well as "resume" buttons.

Comment: @MonaJalal Then just have you `Button_Start` method call `Resume()` instead of `Start()`. You can delete the `Start()` method, as `Resume()` already has the correct logic for this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pause/resume the **`DispatcherTimer`**, you need to use the `.IsEnabled` property. The reason `Restart` methods lack its related of the Framework you are using. This is not the full .Net Framework, just a sub-set of it. Exactly that @Ergwun said.

Comment: And try to figure out if you aren't calling the Reset method. I've made a simple test here, and the Stopwatch Stop/Start methods worked fine. Without resetting the elapsed time.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the lines you are calling the `Reset()` method and check when it is called. Hope it can help.